# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' and json expected

Tags: python, json, list, attributes, locust

I noticed something, as I am trying to setup a sample Restful API test project using this site - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/. According to the docs on the site, when trying to make a post call I just need to pass the `id`, all I need to do is to call the endpoint thus: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4, this should return this:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 4,
  "title": "et porro tempora",
  "completed": true
}
```

Whenever I pass only the ID in my post call using Python LocustIO, I'm getting 500 server error, it only do return 201, which is success when I add the whole json object like this:

```
 {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 4,
      "title": "et porro tempora",
      "completed": true
 }
```

And secondly when I on this line it will always return :

```
if sorted(a.items()) == sorted(b.items()):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

What's the way forward, as this thread did not solve the problem - [Python WordCloud meet AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994551/python-wordcloud-meet-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-items)?

Comment: to fix `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'` Error just do this 
if sorted(a) == sorted(b): because your object a and b are lists, dictionary objects have attribute named items not lists .

Comment: Thanks @toheedNiaz, this solved the problem instantly. appreciate a bunch. What about the json passed?

Comment: Didn't read the doc, but I believe you'd have to make a GET request